# How to calculate time duration with ESP8266 asleep?

Tags: time, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266, sleep-mode

My project uses a force sensing resistor to detect occupancy. A timer will count the duration of the occupancy and update the server. I would like to put the ESP8266 wifi chip to sleep instead of being awake throughout the occupancy. The goal is to save unnecessary battery consumption.

Is there a way to have a snapshot of the time of occupancy and time when the person leaves the chair to calculate the duration of occupancy?

```
if(sensorReading >= 150) // Condition when someone is sitting; sensitivity level.
  {

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
    {
     delay(500);
     Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");

    client.print("[Chair is occupied]\r\n");
    digitalWrite(2,LOW);                 // When condition is true, Blue LED light up for as long User1 is sitting.
    colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 0), 50); // Red;  (x,x,x) is the colour decimal, <number> refers to the speed at which the dots are occupied.

    if(count ==0)
    {
      StarWars();
      count++;  
    }
    else
    {
      noTone(SPEAKER);
    }

    finished=millis();                             // End stopwatch timer count
    duration=finished-start;

    h=int(duration/3600000);                        // conversion to hours from ms (60*60*1000)
    over=duration%3600000;
    m=int(over/60000);                              // conversion to mins from ms (60*1000)
    over=over%60000;
    s=int(over/1000);                               // conversion to sec from ms (1000)
    ms=over%1000;

    client.print(" Duration of occupancy: ");
    client.print(h,0);                              // show only integer
    client.print("h ");
    client.print(m,0);                              // show only integer
    client.print("m ");
    client.print(s,0);                              // show only integer
    client.print("s ");
    client.print(ms,0);                             // show only integer
    client.println("ms");

    a = TotalTime;                                 // let a = TotalTime
    b = duration;                                    // let b = duration
  }
```

Comment: How did you solve your problem in the end?